# Is there a way to use cocoasudo (graphical “sudo” for Mac OS X) in Electron/Node app?

Tags: javascript, bash, electron, sudo, child-process

I am spawning a child process with root privileges in my Electron app for macos. Things are working fine but app is asking for root password on command line instead of user interface.

```
var cProcess = require('child_process');
var terminal = cProcess.spawn('sudo',['bash']);
terminal.stdin.write('rm /private/var/log/wifi.log');
```

I want a dialogue box for asking password from user instead. I found [cocoasudo](http://www.performantdesign.com/2009/10/26/cocoasudo-a-graphical-cocoa-based-alternative-to-sudo/) that can be helpful and it seems that it can be used with Electron from this [thread](https://github.com/jorangreef/sudo-prompt/issues/42#issuecomment-356436034). But I could not figure out How...

There is another question with similar problem, but it is not helpful in my case. Also a [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-sudo/v/3.0.9) exist but not working.

Comment: Why are you spawning a full shell (with root privileges!) instead of just running `rm` with `sudo`?

Comment: @chepner I need to run such commands throughout my application. At multiple times. Please check this question for detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54652002/how-can-i-take-persistent-permissions-in-electron-app